# Can't get table data from grid formatted website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data from https://www.lipidmaps.org/databases/lmsd/LMSL01010001. I usually use beautifulsoup or pandas to extract table data. But the tables in the website dont seem to have been made with the table class. For example, the Calculated Physicochemical Properties table has been made with "flex-grow flex-shrink p-3 px-5".

How can I extract the data from the tables (specifically Calculated Physicochemical Properties table and SMILES value)?

I tried the following code but I get almost the whole websites text:
'soup.find("div")'.

I usually use `pandas.read_table(link)`

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of getting that information, and displaying it into a dataframe format:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

big_list = []
r = requests.get('https://www.lipidmaps.org/databases/lmsd/LMSL01010001', headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
smiles = soup.select_one('div:-soup-contains("SMILES") > span:-soup-contains("(Click to copy)")').find_next('div').text.strip()
heavy_atoms = soup.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Heavy Atoms")').find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()
rings = soup.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Rings")').find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()
big_list.append((smiles, heavy_atoms, rings))
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns=['SMILES', 'Heavy Atoms', 'Rings'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    SMILES  Heavy Atoms Rings
0   O(P(O)(=O)OC[C@@H]1[C@@H](O)[C@@H](O)[C@H](N2C(=O)NC(=O)C=C2)O1)P(O[C@H]1O[C@@H]([C@H]([C@@H]([C@H]1N)OC(C[C@@H](CCCCCCCCCCC)O)=O)O)CO)(=O)O    52  3
```

You can get the other datapoints as well, using the logic above. Also, make sure your packages are up to date.
BeautifulSoup documentation can be found [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you Barry the Platipus. Really appreciate it. I will try it on the other datapoints too

Comment: Hi Barry. I have been able to modify the code to get the other datapoints. However, I can't get it to work to get teh systematic name, and the pubchem CID. I tried: `soup.select_one('div:-soup-contains("PubChem CID")').find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()`

I also tried changing the string to float = True

Comment: You need to get creative in your usage of BeautifulSoup. For example, `sys_name = soup.select_one('div[class^="col-span-12 md:col-span-4"]').find_next('div').text.strip()`. Documentation for BeautifulSoup can be found [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and for soupsieve(the library used by bs4 for css selectors) can be found [here](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/)